# How to disable adding new rows/cols in handsontable?

Tags: jquery, handsontable

First of all, there is an well-known bug with `handsontable` (which is a great piece of code anyway), mentioned by e.g. [user tezhm](https://github.com/tezhm), on [official github issues list for handsontable](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/1370):

> When selecting a cell on the last row of a table and drag-selecting below the row
>   into an area outside of the table, the scroll viewport is triggered causing 
>   a malfunction of the view. This can be recreated using the demo tables.

Because of it, I decided to either turn off scrollbars completely or disable adding new rows/cols.

**But how to disable adding new rows/cols in `handsontable`?**

Alternatively, **how to disable scrolling in `handsontable`?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To disable adding new rows/columns, set the following options:

```
minSpareRows: 0,
minSpareCols: 0
```

If you are using a context menu, you can disable the functionality with:

```
contextMenu: ["undo", "redo"]
```

Another option could be to set `maxRows` to the number of rows in your data and `maxCols` to the number of columns in your data. Note: if you are using the `columns` option, `maxCols` will be ignored.

```
maxRows: data.numberOfRows,
maxCols: data.numberOfColumns
```

Answer (score 3):

I have tried

```
minSpareRows: 0,
minSpareCols: 0
```

But no luck :(.

Finally, I tried something like the following:

```
afterCreateRow: function (index, numberOfRows) {
                    data.splice(index, numberOfRows);
                }
```

It did the work :)

Comment: That's another way to go, I guess. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use below options , this works for me..

```
fillHandle: {
      direction: 'vertical',
      autoInsertRow: false,
    }
```